# hyperlink in localized.strings file - objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, localization

Is it possible to embed a working html hyperlink inside a localized string file? And if so, how?

When I try to create this link I get an error:

read failed: The data couldn’t be read because it has been corrupted.

I think it is in the **"** of the url. Reading this character the strings file "thinks" the string has ended. "*http://...

Please advice.

**Edit:**
"Disclaimer" = "Door het .... Voor meer informatie zie ook: [hier](http://www.apple.com/legal/internet-services/itunes/appstore/dev/stdeula/) \n\n\n";

Comment: Can you post the full line from your strings file, that causes the problem?

Answer (score 4):

Quotation marks inside `"key" = "value";` in the strings file
have to be escaped with a backslash character:

```
"link" = "<a href=\"http://stackoverflow.com\">stackoverflow</a>";
```

In your case:

```
"Disclaimer" = "Door het .... Voor meer informatie zie ook: <a href=\"http://www.apple.com/legal/internet-services/itunes/appstore/dev/stdeula/\">hier</a> \n\n\n";
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried it and the error is gone. However, it is not a working link but is displayed as plain text. How come?

Comment: @AdriOosterwijk: That is a completely different problem. How do you display the text? I think that you need a NSAttributedString or UIWebView, a plain NSString will not work.

Comment: Ah, ok. That is what I was affraid for. Just because it is inside a localized string wich is displayed in a multi-line textField. I simply have to find another solution. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @AdriOosterwijk: Your question was how to embed a html link in a strings file, which I have tried to answer. Displaying a html link in UITextField or UITextView is a completely different problem, so you might consider to accept this answer and post a new question if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Check the following:

- That your strings in the `Localizable.strings` file are NOT prefixed with "@".
- That every line ends in ";".
- The file is UTF-16 encoded (you can check that running `file Localizable.strings` from Terminal.

Example of line in `Localizable.strings`:

> "My awesome string" = "Mi estupenda cadena";